# How can I make jQuery select an element in the style of CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

`<div id="id" class="div-style"><img id="id" class="img-style"></div>`

I would like to use the id attribute as a way for jQuery to select the element, and the class attribute for CSS to style it.

My guess for jQuery selector ran thusly:

`$("#id .div-class")`

and

`$("#id .img-class")`

This returns the error "Selector expected"

Comment: Where do `div-class` and `img-class` come from?

Comment: Pekka, they are example names of CSS styles. Or were you asking something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
$("#id .div-class")
```

and

```
$("#id .img-class")
```

attempts to select descendent elements with CSS class 'div-class' and 'img-class' of the element with id `id`, respectively, which won't return anything. Selecting an element by id is the fastest way and you wouldn't need to specify the CSS class if using id, since the HTML specification states that elements ids should be unique within a page. So, using just

```
$("#id")
```

will select the div with id `id`. Now what would you like to do with the element?

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute should (as per HTML standard specifications) be unique across all elements in a page. Thus, if that `<div>` is the only element in your page with the `id` attribute set to `"id"`, then you can safely use `$("#id")`.